# internal logrotate mechanism in syslog-ng

Tags: logrotate, linux-audit, syslog-ng

Does the syslog-ng has its own rotating mechanism?
I am new to auditing and linux and I though I could use logrotate but I noticed that I need to restart the syslog-ng daemon every time when I use it to rotate the logs.

Having said that, I think that syslog-ng must have some sort of internal mechanism to achieve the same goal and if it does not what are my other options. Maybe using macros and creating folders for each ${HOUR}${DAY} etc?

Thank's in advance.

Comment: Why do you think that? What's wrong with restarting?

Comment: Well, a colleague told me that this will lead to loss of data as indeed when I manually rotate one file the syslog-ng service stopped and I had to restart it manually. He mentioned something about two processes accessing the same file simultaneously was not a good idea. He might be wrong though.

Comment: From my reading, you could change the config file to point to the new log file, and send syslog-ng a `SIGHUP` to make it reread the config.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit further please.

Comment: Read `man date`, and decide on a format for the time/date part of the log file name (avoid spaces and other special characters). Then use `sed` (read `man sed`) to replace `date --date="yesterday"` (in your selected format) with `date --date="today"`. Then read `man kill pkill signal` and tell `syslog-ng` to reread its config file with `pkill -HUP syslog-ng`. Read `man syslog-ng syslog-ng.conf`.

Comment: Many thanks for the elaboration.